# Google mock - at least one of multiple expectations

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I'm using Google Mock to specify a compatibility layer to an external API. In the external API, there are multiple ways to do some actions, so I want to specify that at least one (or preferably exactly one) expectation from a set of expectations are fulfilled. In pseudocode, this is what I want to do:

```
Expectation e1 = EXPECT_CALL(API, doFoo(...));
Expectation e2 = EXPECT_CALL(API, doFooAndBar(...));
EXPECT_ONE_OF(e1, e2);
wrapper.foo(...);
```

Is this possible to do using Google Mock?

Comment: `EXPECT_CALL(API, doFoo(_)).Times(1);` works?

Comment: @BЈовић That works as long as `wrapper.foo()` calls `doFoo()`, but I want to test to pass even if `wrapper.foo()` doesn't call `doFoo()`, as long as it calls `doFooAndBar()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible to do in two ways :

1. with custom methods executor - create a class, with the same methods. And then use `Invoke()` to pass the call to that object
2. using partial order call - create different expectations in different sequences, as explained [here](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/V1_7_CookBook#Expecting_Partially_Ordered_Calls)

---

**With custom method executor**

Something like this :

```
struct MethodsTracker {
   void doFoo( int ) {
     ++ n;
   }
   void doFooAndBar( int, int ) {
     ++ n;
   }
   int n;
};

TEST_F( MyTest, CheckItInvokesAtLeastOne ) {
  MethodsTracker tracker;
  Api obj( mock );

  EXPECT_CALL( mock, doFoo(_) ).Times( AnyNumber() ).WillByDefault( Invoke( &tracker, &MethodsTracker::doFoo ) );
  EXPECT_CALL( mock, doFooAndBar(_,_) ).Times( AnyNumber() ).WillByDefault( Invoke( &tracker, &MethodsTracker::doFooAndBar ) );

  obj.executeCall();

  // at least one
  EXPECT_GE( tracker.n, 1 );
}
```

---

**using partial order call**

```
TEST_F( MyTest, CheckItInvokesAtLeastOne ) {
      MethodsTracker tracker;
      Api obj( mock );

      Sequence s1, s2, s3, s4;

      EXPECT_CALL(mock, doFoo(_)).InSequence(s1).Times(AtLeast(1));
      EXPECT_CALL(mock, doFooAndBar(_,_)).InSequence(s1).Times(AtLeast(0));

      EXPECT_CALL(mock, doFoo(_)).InSequence(s2).Times(AtLeast(0));
      EXPECT_CALL(mock, doFooAndBar(_,_)).InSequence(s2).Times(AtLeast(1));

      EXPECT_CALL(mock, doFooAndBar(_,_)).InSequence(s3).Times(AtLeast(0));
      EXPECT_CALL(mock, doFoo(_)).InSequence(s3).Times(AtLeast(1));

      EXPECT_CALL(mock, doFooAndBar(_,_)).InSequence(s4).Times(AtLeast(1));
      EXPECT_CALL(mock, doFoo(_)).InSequence(s4).Times(AtLeast(0));

      obj.executeCall();
}
```

Comment: Partial order call looks like it could get out of hand quickly, but using the custom method executor seems like a suitable solution.